# Dealing with \r \n ^M ^@ in text files using vim

Tags: vim, newline, carriage-return

When I save lines of data in excel files as tab delimited .txt files, and then open those files in VIM, I see that what was once a multi-line file in excel is now a single line file in VIM.

The "lines" can be separated in VIM using some substitution commands:

```
%s/^M/\r\n/g
```

After this, the "lines" are now separated by an `^@`.
I deal with it using another substitution command:

```
%s/^@//g
```

My questions are:

1. Why do my multi-line txt excel files open as a single line in VI?
2. What is `^@`?
3. Is there a better way to 'fix' my txt files?

Comment: i see that ^@ is some kind of Vi specific "null bite" place holder. Is this correct? Still don't get where it comes from...

Comment: What happens when you type `:set ff=dos`?

Comment: what does the `ff` stand for? I'll try that.

Comment: Read here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format.
It sets the fileformat, and therefore the endline char that is used. (So type `:set ff=dos` immediately after you opened your file)

Comment: I'll formulate that as an answer.

Comment: Using `:set ff=dos` does nothing, nothing changes, no characters are replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
    :%s/^M/\r/g
```

`\r` is the carriage return character vim uses. The `^M` character is a newline character that is literally displayed.

Comment: When I use the command `:%s/^M/\n/g` I get an error message that says "Pattern not found".  However, if I use `:%s/^M/\r\n/g` followed by `:%s/^@//g`, it works.

Comment: What OS are you using for excel and for vim?

Comment: hi, I'm using mac OS 10.7.5 Lion for both excel and vim.

Comment: Yeah, since everything is done on a mac, the first suggestion won't work. I assumed excel ran on windows.
About the second part, try `:%s/^M/\r/g`. Should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can often fix problems like this by running the following command:

`dos2unix FILE_NAME`

This will re-format the file's newline characters in place (ie it will modify your file).

(*This command does not exist on Mac OS X*)

---

If you don't have dos2unix (eg you're on a Mac), you can just use sed:

`sed 's/^M$//' input.txt > output.txt`

You can also use `sed -i` if you want to avoid creating a new file by performing the substitution *in place*.

You can enter `^M` by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>

[More reading here](http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2009/04/09/dos2unix-using-sed-how-to-remove-m-chars-from-a-dos-file/)

Comment: Using `dos2unix FILE_NAME` didn't work, the command is not recognized.

Comment: @eric - I doubt it would exist in a Mac environment.  It _does_ exist in my Cygwin and Solaris environments.  That's all I can check at the moment.  I'm not very familiar with tr, but I'm sure there is a simple sed/tr equivalent...

Comment: using `sed -i 's/^M$//' input.txt` gives the following message: `sed: 1: "chr3_F34_map.txt": command c expects \ followed by text`.