# replacing dos2unix line endings

Tags: unix, sed, awk, find

I am using the following code to replace dos2unix line endings.  Every time I execute the code it gets stuck at the command prompt.  What is wrong with the below command?

```
for i in `find . -type f \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" \)`; do    sed -i 's/\r//' $i ; done
```

Comment: Why not just use the `dos2unix` command?

Comment: What platform are you on?  You might want to use xargs depending on the answer...

Comment: @jahroy - I installed dos2unix on my ubuntu but everytime i run it says "dos2unix command not found"

Comment: Sounds like you either didn't install it or didn't install it properly.

Comment: @jahroy - that was a typo....can you suggest any other way other than dos2unix

Comment: There many places on the web that suggest how to do it with sed. I'll see if I can find any old questions on this site...

Comment: Are you sure your find command and for loop work?  I would test that first before testing the sed part.  I'm not an expert with find, but your syntax looks suspicious.  Also, why not combine `.c` and `.h` like this: `-name "*.[ch]"`

Comment: Here's a question with [an answer that shows how to fix newline chars using sed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13772254/778118).

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` are implemented as `todos` and `frodos` respectively. They are available in the package `tofrodos`.

I suggest using

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" \) -print0 | xargs -0 frodos
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest confirming that your find command and for loop work properly.

You can do this by simply using an echo statement to print each file's name.

Depending on your platform (and how many *.c* and *.h* files you have) you might need to use *xargs* instead of directly manipulating the output from find.  It's hard to say, because you still haven't told us which platform you're on.

Also, depending on your platform, different versions of *sed* work differently with the *-i* option.

Sometimes you **MUST** specify a file extension to use for the backup file, sometimes you don't have to.

All of the above are reasons that I suggest testing your command piece by piece.

You should read the man pages for each command you're trying to use on the system on which you're trying to use it.

Regarding the *sed* portion of your command, you should test that on a single file to make sure it works.

You can use the following sed command to fix your newlines:

`sed 's/^M$//' input.txt > output.txt`

You can type the `^M` by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>

Like I said before, the `-i` option works differently on different platforms.

If you have trouble getting that to work, you could have sed output a new file and then overwrite the original file afterwards.

This would be very simple to do inside your for loop.